# Testing UWP apps on different builds of Windows?

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps

I built an app targeting Windows 10240 and above. However, I mistakenly used the `Windows.Services.Store` namespace for IAP in an update.

This made it through review, and now I'm seeing crash reports from users on older builds of Windows 10.

Is there a way I can test that my app runs successfully on these older builds?

(Excluding starting up four VMs, or building testing PCs if possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to test properly is to use VMs or actual machines; there's no way to have Windows "forget" that an API actually exists. (Windows will emulate the *behaviour* of older OS releases depending on your `MaxVersionTested` attribute, but it won't stop your app from accessing the newer APIs).

The way you can conditionally call APIs is via the [`ApiInformation` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation) - if it's there, use it, otherwise don't.

Comment: What do you think of using one Windows 2 Go per OS version?

Comment: I've never tried that myself but if it works for you, great!